# Can I create an LUT which provides solid lines?

Tags: lut

I understand that a LUT is roughly a structure which converts every pixel of an image from RGB(r1,g1,b1) to RGB(r2,g2,b2) which means that it executes a color transformation.

I have a field monitor which can use external LUTs but provides only a few build in grids. I would like to use my own grids like user defined aspect ratio borders, dynamic symmetry lines etc.

I wonder if there is a way to provide these grid lines via a LUT, like merge some lines drawn on an alpha channel layer and merge it to an image or something like that.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.